# Xcode noob: Don't understand compiler error message

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm fairly new to Xcode and have recently gotten an error message that is probably clear to anyone who knows what they're doing, but I am unsure how to react to this one.

I have a project that is mostly C++, with just a few C files in it. Everything was fine until I tried to add some code to find the computer's MAC address. Apple provides a project example (GetPrimaryMACAddress), and I downloaded, built, and tested that. It works just fine.

After that, I simply copied the C source from the Apple example project and included it into my code project. Then I started getting this error message:
[image]

I have tried including the IOKit framework explicitly via the linker; no help. I tried adding more `#include` statement to the Apple example code; no help. I think that I do not understand what the compiler message is telling me regarding importing from module 'Darwin.MacTypes'.

Clicking on the error message took me to a line in usr/include/MacTypes.h:
[image]

I'm not clear on how to `Import` Darwin.MacTypes. I don't really understand how the source code for GetMACAddress could compile so effortlessly in one project and not another. I didn't rearrange nor add nor delete any of the `#include` statements in the Apple-supplied C file.

I'll bet there is a simple answer that I am just not seeing. How should I react to this error message?

Comment: Show the includes and imports at the top of the `.c` file which is being built when this error occurs. I suspect the difference between the projects is that the Apple sample does **not** have `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES` set in the build settings, while your new one does. You could try turning it off.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with types like UInt16 and UInt32. I just included the MacTypes with the following include statement:

```
#include <MacTypes.h>
```

This solved all my type-problems for my example c-file.

Answer (score -2):

Let me guess, when you want to compile C++ source, you should create a **C++ source** file

(On the toolbar: File > New > File.. > Source > C++ File)

Comment: That response has nothing whatsoever to do with my question. As I already pointed out, my mostly-C++ project already had a few C files in it; there was no problem until I added the Apple-supplied source code.